# Add vibration to incoming Signal messages (iOS)

Tags: vibrate, signal

Similarly to incoming iMessages I want vibrations on incoming Signal (https://signal.org/) messages.

Is this doable as of now?

Comment: Were notifications allowed for the app ? Please check the vibrate on ring and vibrate on silent switches in sounds settings.

Answer (score 1):

On IPhone SE the only options under Signal->Notifications are enabling/disabling Sounds and Badges. Not even the default ding/bell sound is modifiable.